# Find first space and cut all the left content in a string on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

In JavaScript, I have strings like:

```
"US$ 43,22"
"$ 2,44"
```

And I need to find the first space and cut the left content to have something like this:

```
"43,22"
"2,44"
```

Anyone knows how to do it? The point here is find the space.

Thank's very much in advance!

**EDIT:**

If I do:

```
console.log(retrievedPrice); //Have "US$ 35,88" 

let priceWithoutCurrency = retrievedPrice.substr(retrievedPrice.indexOf(' ') + 1);
console.log(priceWithoutCurrency); //I have the same: "US$ 35,88"
```

Why?

Comment: What if there are two spaces? No space at all?

Comment: Mmm only I'll have one space, but with no space at all, could be a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below code snippet

```js
var string = "US$ 43,22";
console.log( string.substr(string.indexOf(" ")+1))
```

Update:

```js
 var string = "US$ 43,22";
 var result = string.substr(string.indexOf(" ")+1);
 console.log(result);
```

```js
let retrievedPrice = "US$ 43,22";
let priceWithoutCurrency = retrievedPrice.substr(retrievedPrice.indexOf(' ') + 1);
console.log(priceWithoutCurrency);
```

Comment: It includes the space in the result. :) I think you want `indexOf(" ") + 1`

Comment: If I do:
`console.log(retrievedPrice); //Have "US$ 35,88"`

`let priceWithoutCurrency = retrievedPrice.substr(retrievedPrice.indexOf(' ') + 1);

console.log(priceWithoutCurrency); //I have the same: "US$ 35,88"`

Why?

Answer (score 3):

```js
const s = "US$ 43,22";

const r = s.substr(s.indexOf(' ') + 1);

console.log(r)
```

+1 is needed to cut the space itself.

Comment: @IvanLencina here is your code: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/wk4frb98/ it works as intended, you get the subsctracted number.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const x = "US$ 43,22";
const result = x.split(' ')[1];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Console.log returns null to me with this method :/

Comment: You must be doing it wrong? Run the code here - it logs properly. Maybe try replacing `const` with `var`.

Answer (score 0):

I see it's only a space, right? Try this

```
var myVal = "US$ 43,22";
myVal = myVal.replace("US$ ", "");
```

Comment: That doesn't help for the second case, though.

Comment: Yes but sometimes I have "US$" and sometimes "$"